# Can't reorder AspectJ task in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, aspectj, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 4.5.1, `gradle-aspectj` 2.0 plugin and some others. The problem is that `aspectj`'s task `compileAspect` is being executed before `compileJava`. Seems like I've found [a problem here](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/9cf44ebf5ecb8073db9eb9a5230e4c69558f0268/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy#L63). So I've tried to reorder the tasks execution in the following way:

```
project.tasks['compileJava'].dependsOn.remove(project.tasks['compileAspect'])
project.tasks['compileAspect'].dependsOn(project.tasks['compileJava'])
```

I've also tried almost the same replacing `project.tasks[taskName]` with `taskName`. However, after reorderig `compileAspect` task is being ignored (completely, not skipped). What's more: although `compileJava` seems to be executed it doesn't produce any classes in the `build/classes` directory.

I am new to Gradle so maybe I'm doing a mistake somewhere in the reordering? Please, see [the Github repository](https://github.com/dmitrysenkovich/gradle_ignores_aspectj_task) as an example producing the issue.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's more: although compileJava seems to be executed it doesn't produce any classes in the build/classes directory.

This seems to be the intention of the *Gradle AspectJ plugin*. The line before the one you linked ([62](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/9cf44ebf5ecb8073db9eb9a5230e4c69558f0268/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy#L62)) contains:

```
project.tasks[javaTaskName].deleteAllActions()
```

This causes the `compileJava` task to do nothing at all and this is why, for the plugin, the order of the tasks does not matter. The plugin aims to completely replace `compileJava` task with its `compileAspect` task.

Please note, that the *Gradle AspectJ plugin* was [archived four months ago](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/commit/9cf44ebf5ecb8073db9eb9a5230e4c69558f0268):

> We do not use this code any longer and this repository has been archived.

If you plan to use both compilation steps (Java and AspectJ) in one build, you may create your own plugin. Maybe you can fork the existing project and reuse the task class.

Comment: ok, got it, I should just leave `aspectj` plugin, that was my mistake. I thought aspects are being compiled after compiling java but they seem to be compiled from source, got it. thank you, you're awesome!

Comment: FYI, the AspectJ compiler is an extended and slightly modified version of the Eclipse Java compiler (gets refreshed from there regularly) and thus a complete replacement of the JDK's compiler. This is why neither Gradle AspectJ plugin nor AspectJ Maven plugin need an additional Java compiler. The AspectJ compiler can be configured to only target *.aj files, though and leave *.java untouched. It is just not necessary usually.

Comment: @kriegaex thank you very much for clarifying! it's great to see such a consistent explanation:)